# Spring boot actuator start up error - PatternSyntaxException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.5 version. I upgraded my existing working ap from spring boot 2.3.9 version. I included actuator in pom file. When I start spring boot app, its failing with below error at start up.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmxMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/jmx/JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/env/EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.env.EnvironmentEndpoint]: Factory method 'environmentEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 26
.*PropertiesPropertySource {name='management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize'}$
                          ^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.albertsons.ecommerce.oslm.EventDataServiceApplication.main(EventDataServiceApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/env/EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.env.EnvironmentEndpoint]: Factory method 'environmentEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 26
.*PropertiesPropertySource {name='management.endpoint.env.keys-to-sanitize'}$
```

Below is my dependency version list. I am using almost all starters in pom like web , webflux.
spring-boot-starter-parent : 2.5.5
spring-cloud.version       : 2020.0.3
spring-cloud-services.version: 3.2.1.RELEASE

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: To hopefully avoid wasted time due to duplicated effort, please be aware that this has been cross-posted to Spring Boot’s issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29977

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue by enabling JMX. The bug is due to piece of code in the Spring Cloud Services Connector project. I will raise an issue on their github issue tracker.